# How to prove that the second-stage value function of a Stochastic Program is convex?

Tags: convex-optimization, stochastic-programming

I am wondering to know how it is possible to prove that the second-stage value function in a two-stage stochastic program is convex on $x$ and $\xi$? A two-stage stochastic program can be defined as
\begin{align}\min&\quad c^\top x+\mathcal{Q}(x)\\\text{s.t.}&\quad Ax=b\\&\quad x \ge 0\end{align} where \begin{align}\mathcal{Q}(x)&= E_{\xi}[Q(x,\xi)]
\\Q(x,\xi)&= \min d(\xi)^\top y\\Wy&=h(\xi)-T(\xi)x\end{align}

How is it possible to prove that $Q(x,\xi)$ is convex on both $x$ and $\xi$? For example, when $Q(x,\xi)$ is defined as follows, how to prove the convexity?

\begin{align}\min&\quad\xi_1 y_1+y_2
\\\text{s.t.}&\quad2y_1+3y_2 \ge 1- 2x_1
\\&\quad y_2 \ge \xi_2-x_1-2x_2
\\&\quad y_1,y_2 \ge 0\end{align}

Comment: Are there any assumptions on the functions $h(\cdot), T(\cdot)$? In your example $T(\xi)$ did not depend on $\xi$ and $h(\xi)$ was just linear. Is that the special case you are interested in?

Comment: Those are just linear. Yeah, in my example, $T(.)$ does not depend on $\xi$. But, I wanted to know how to prove it for the general case and if possible, for this example.

Answer (score 2):

Standard assumption: we write a general second-stage problem as $Q(x,\xi)=\min_y\{q^\top y\mid Wy=h-Tx\}$ and $\xi=(q,W,T,h)$. In your example $W$ and $T$ are fixed (not stochastic) while $q=(\xi_1,1)$ and $h=(1,\xi_2)$ are stochastic.

Now, $Q(x,\xi)$ is convex in $h$, $T$ and $x$ but is concave in $q$. So, saying that $Q(x,\xi)$ is, in general, convex in $x$ and $\xi$ is wrong, except if $q$ is fixed. $Q(x)$ is the expectation of a convex function and, as such, is convex. In your specific case, the second-stage problem is convex in $x$ and $\xi_2$, and is concave in $\xi_1$

To see that $Q(x,\xi)$ is convex in $h$, $T$ and $x$, simply observe that they appear in the right-hand-side of the problem. Now, a minimization linear program is always convex in its right-hand-side. To prove that an LP is convex in its RHS let $t=h-Tx$. Consider $t_1$ and $t_2$ and $t^{\alpha}=\alpha t_1+(1-\alpha)t_2$ with $\alpha\in[0,1]$. Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the optimal solution to $f(t)=\min_y\{q^\top y\mid Wy=t\}$ for $t=t_1$ and $t=t_2$, respectively. It is easy to see that $y^{\alpha}= \alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2$ is feasible for $f(t^{\alpha})=\min_y\{q^\top y\mid Wy=t^{\alpha}\}$ (it satisfies the constraints). However, it is not necessarily optimal. Let $y^{\alpha*}$ be the optimal solution to $f(t^{\alpha})$. We can write
\begin{align*}f(t^{\alpha})&=q^\top y^{\alpha*}\leq q^\top y^{\alpha}\\
&=q^\top(\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2)=\alpha (q^\top y_1)+(1-\alpha)(q^\top y_2)\\
&=\alpha f(t_1)+(1-\alpha)f(t_2)\end{align*}
Which proves convexity. To make the proof more rigorous one must specify how the RHS vectors are chosen. [This article](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0114008) clarifies that the set of RHSs which make the problem feasible is a polyhedral cone. However, this should suffice for now.

To see that is its concave in $q$ observe that $q$ shows up in the right-hand-side of the dual of $Q(x,\xi)$, which is a maximization linear program. A maximization LP is always concave in its right-hand-side.
The proof proceeds with the same steps used to prove convexity above.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, how to prove that " minimization linear program is always convex in its right-hand-side". Another difference with my example is that $\xi_1$ is in the objective function.

Comment: A good proof of that statement is given, for example, in R. Wets *PROGRAMMING UNDER UNCERTAINTY: THE EQUIVALENT CONVEX PROGRAM* 1966 in an appendix. Your $\xi_1$ in the objective function coincides with a component of $q$ in the standard formulation. You have $q=(\xi_1,1)$.